# Change of rules & regulations after accepting faculty contract offer

Tags: salary, contract, netherlands

I have recently accepted a new academic position in the Netherlands. Netherlands has a generous so-called 30% rule for high skilled expats:

> you are paying taxes only for the 70% of your income and the rest 30%
> is given to you as a tax-free allowance. This, in practice, means
> about 20% higher net salary.

I easily got this rule 2 years ago for another academic position again in NL. The duration for the 30% rule is 8 years so I should have it for the next 6 years and nobody from HR mentioned any plans from the government of reducing it. Unfortunately, yesterday I read in the news that Dutch government completed a draft proposal which reduces the 30% rule from 8 to 5 years.  What is worth noting is that, in case the draft becomes a law (which most probably will, since this is the *final* proposal) will have [a retroactive effect :](https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/documenten/kamerstukken/2018/04/20/kabinetsreactie-evaluatie-30-regeling)

> Concreet betekent dit dat het kabinet in het pakket Belastingplan 2019
> zal voorstellen de maximale looptijd van de 30%-regeling met ingang
> van 1 januari 2019 voor zowel nieuwe ***als bestaande gevallen met drie
> jaar te verkorte**n*.​

One of the factors that made me accepted the new offer was the 30% rule for the remaining 6 years (I planned to buy house immediately). Now I see that this might not very well be true. What is even worse is that I turned down a great Research position (in a high tech company) offering about 60% more salary. I thought the 30% rule would partly compensate about it, but probably it will not.

I will not ask about the legal aspects of the draft law nor about the ethical dimension of this although you can see here what the [relevant tax authorities say](https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontenten/belastingdienst/individuals/living_and_working/working_in_another_country_temporarily/you_are_coming_to_work_in_the_netherlands/30_facility_for_incoming_employees/the_decision_issued_to_you_has_a_maximum_term_of_8_years) about shortening the period of 8 years.

> Is it too late to turn down the academic offer? I have accepted it on e-mail but I haven't signed anything yet and haven't even seen the contract. If yes, what is the best way to do this?
>
> Is anything similar happening to any other country and how do academics people deal with it?

Apparently, a lot of expats taking advantage of this rule get frustrated and set up an [e-vote against the draft](https://www.change.org/p/iamexpat-transitional-law-for-30-rulings-granted-in-2014-and-earlier?recruiter=872328286&utm_source=share_petition&utm_medium=copylink&utm_campaign=share_petition&utm_term=share_for_starters_page).

Comment: I suggest that you ask the accounting office or the professors' union or professional organization about this before you send anything to the department.  It would be important to find out how the university is thinking of handling this in general before you give the department any hint that you are getting cold feet.  Please keep in mind that this change, if implemented as described, would affect a lot of other university employees too.  The university may be making plans for dealing with this.

Comment: @aparente001 Thank you. I asked, and they were not even aware of that! Apparently, there is a huge amount of frustration in the expat community in NL taking advantage of this rule. There are even on-line petitions, for whoever is willing to sign (see my update question). But for some reason I lost any confidence that this will work out...

Comment: Have you reached out to the other offer to see if the position is still open?  I mean, if your gut feeling has turned sour about the teaching job, then....

Comment: One other thought.  You might take a look at the university's hierarchy chart and talk to someone high up in finances.  If they haven't published their hierarchy chart, then you could find out who's who by phoning a secretary in the office of whoever's at the top of the university administration.  At least, this approach has served me well in the US.

Comment: What we have here is the government behaving unlawfully. They will get away with it because there is no higher power that can require them to behave; but the behavior is unlawful by nature. This is a proven theorem both in computer science and in insurance risk calculation.

Comment: @Joshua I'm not an expert in Dutch law, so can you explain what's unlawful here?

Comment: @AzorAhai: Retroactive laws are inherently unlawful because it is necessary to have a lawful society for people to be able to depend on knowing what the law is.

Comment: @joshua: That's bollocks. The government allowed people every year they file a tax return to only count 70% of their income for 8 years, to allowing that to happen for only 5 years. They're not asking you to pay back taxes for previous years -- they simply don't extend a benefit people have enjoyed for as long as they did. By your logic, governments could never increase taxes.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: The only part that is unlawful is the part that says "will have a retroactive effect". They can change the tax law and it goes into effect that day forward just fine.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth As I said, I am not qualified to discuss the legal aspect of the proposal. However, keep in mind that many people (myself included) made plans based on the duration of 8 years for this rule (and this is what is written in the document I received from the tax authorities). Now imagine you have a mortgage or a newborn child and made concrete plans based on that, only to suddenly realize that this will change to the worse _without_ any provision.

Comment: @PsySp out of curiosity, are you currently employed by another institute, or is this going to be your first paid position (given that you accept the offer)?

Comment: @padawan I have been already under this rule for the last 2 years in NL, employed at a university.

Comment: @PsySp: I totally understand that you are annoyed, but everyone else is in the same position that a tax raise disrupts their plans to pay down mortgages etc. Governments raise or lower taxes all the time.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth - Thanks for clarifying the limited extent to which this change is *retroactive*.  That term as OP used it gave me an inaccurate impression. // I think your main point is important, that OP is by far not the only person affected by such a change.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I do not understand what you mean: you equalize a tax raise with this particular rule that would lower my income by 20-21% for 3 years? This is a severe measure and affects the plans made by a lot of expats that were promised an 8-year period under this rule. I do not think this is a good analogy.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth _they simply don't extend a benefit people have enjoyed for as long as they did._ No! We were promised 8-year period under this rule. It is not matter of _extension_. Is matter of reducing the promised period without transitional provisions (like they did in 2012 when they reduced it from 10 to 8 years _only_ for new cases).

Comment: @aparente001 Noone said that I am the only one: All expats that were promised by the government 8 year application of this rule (and made certain decisions based on that) are affected.

Comment: @PsySp: You'll have to show me the place in the tax law that promises the benefit for 8 years into the future. Any reasonable person would write the tax code as saying something along the lines of "Holders of an XY visa will only have to state 70% of their income as taxable as long as they have not claimed this benefit for more than the past 8 years." That's not a promise. If your employer *sold* you this as a promise, then that's their promise, but I'd be quite surprised if the tax code made this promise this way.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontenten/belastingdienst/individuals/living_and_working/working_in_another_country_temporarily/you_are_coming_to_work_in_the_netherlands/30_facility_for_incoming_employees/the_decision_issued_to_you_has_a_maximum_term_of_8_years 
from the Dutch tax authorities, where it says _specifically_ when the rule should be less than 8 years and when the rule would not shorten. I do not know how more clear this could be. All the rest are legal shenanigans.

Comment: @PsySp -- `<shrug>`. That may be advisory information from the Dutch tax service, but it's not the law. I guess you will have to sue the Dutch government to get a legally binding decision.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth You were talking about the tax code and I cite the tax authorities (belonging to the ministry). I do not know how more relevant it can get. As I said, I did not want to delve into the legality of the proposal. Technically speaking, it _may_  be legal (but I think even the most qualified lawyers will have hard time). However this raises a moral/ethical dimension especially in a country where a handshake is considered a contract and the whole economy, historically, is based on the element of _trust_ and this bait-and-switch is not working for me.

Answer (score 12):

This is an unfortunate situation were nobody really is to blame. You can't expect the university to warn you about a law that wasn't even in place yet, and the university cannot objectively be mad at you for reneging when your contractual situation significantly changed, even if it is due to outside factors. Of course the important word in the above statement is "objectively" - nobody can ensure you that the people that wanted to hire you will also see it like that, and that you won't burn any bridges.

> Is it too late to turn down the academic offer? I have accepted it on e-mail but I haven't signed anything yet and haven't even seen the contract. If yes, what is the best way to do this?

As long as you have not signed anything you are always in the right to back out. The best way to do it would be to warn them that this new development significantly changes your view on their offer, even if they are of course not to blame. I would stay clear of any accusations that they failed to inform you in advance. Note that this also gives them the option to up their offer, which would presumably change your mind back again.

You should do it in the same form as you tentatively accepted the offer before - if you communicated that you would take the offer via email, send them a brief follow-up that you changed your mind, and why.

> Is anything similar happening to any other country and how do academics people deal with it?

I am not aware of any concrete cases, but presumably when Brexit broke there had to be cases of academics changing their mind about moving to the UK.

Comment: thank you. The point is that (as Dutch people say) they consider a verbal agreement or an e-mail agreement as a contract. Of course this adds to the cultural situation. In any case, I do not blame them (I am willing to believe that this is just unfortunate) butt the difference on my salary for the next 6 years (taking into account the offer I turned down) would be up to 90-100k and naturally I am have double and triple thoughts on how to handle it.

Answer (score 7):

While there are probably nuances to the situation, this sounds a lot like the tax laws have changed resulting in you having a much higher tax liability. Maybe the university will be nice and offer everyone a raise to account for the change in the tax law, but most likely (at least in the US), the university is not particularly worried about your take home pay.

Having accepted the contract in an email, but not having signed it yet, puts you in a gray area. Changing your mind immediately after a change in the tax law is announce, or even proposed, that will result in a 20% reduction in salary, seems reasonable. A quick email to the department chair saying you just read about the tax change and that by your calculations that reduces your take home pay from X to Y and that makes the position untenable for you.

Even if you had signed the contract (either from a legal or cultural stand point), you can still change you mind. If you legally signed it, they can come after you for breach of contract, but no employer wants to hire someone who is going to start unhappy with their contract. The more committed the department thinks you are and the more work they have put into closing the search (e.g., if they already told the alternative candidates that they were not hired), the more likely they are going to be upset at you.